# How to inject vendor class to Service?

Tags: php, symfony, solid-principles, symfony-3.4

I have example service:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Entity\Article;
use CompanyName\Utils\ClassFromVendor;

class DecorateArticle
{
    private $customDecorator;
    private $article;

    public function __construct(CustomDecorator $customDecorator)
    {
        $this->customDecorator = $customDecorator;
    }

    public function setNews(Article $article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;
    }

    public function decorate() : string
    {
         $text = strip_tags($this->article->getBody());

         $text = $this->customDecorator->doIt($text);

         $classFromVendor = new ClassFromVendor();
         $text = $classFromVendor->doIt($text);

         return $text;
    }
}

//controller:

public function showToApiAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $news = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:News')->find($request->get('id'));

    $decorateArticle = $this->get('AppBundle\Service\DecorateArticle');
    $decorateArticle->setNews($news);

    return $decorateArticle->decorate();
}

//services.yml:

AppBundle\Service\DecorateArticle:
    arguments:
        $decorateArticle: '@AppBundle\Service\DecorateArticle'
    public: true
```

Everything works well in this code, but my Team Leader told me that it breaks the SOLID principle.

That's why I did:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Entity\Article;
use CompanyName\Utils\ClassFromVendor;

class DecorateArticle
{
    private $customDecorator;
    private $classFromVendor;
    private $article;

    public function __construct(CustomDecorator $customDecorator, ClassFromVendor $classFromVendor)
    {
        $this->customDecorator = $customDecorator;
        $this->classFromVendor = $classFromVendor;
    }

    public function setNews(Article $article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;
    }

    public function decorate() : string
    {
         $text = strip_tags($this->article->getBody());

         $text = $this->customDecorator->doIt($text);

         $text = $this->classFromVendor->doIt($text);

         return $text;
    }
}

//controller:

public function showToApiAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $news = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:News')->find($request->get('id'));

    $decorateArticle = $this->get('AppBundle\Service\DecorateArticle');
    $decorateArticle->setNews($news);

    return $decorateArticle->decorate();
}

//services.yml:

AppBundle\Service\DecorateArticle:
    arguments:
        $decorateArticle: '@AppBundle\Service\DecorateArticle'
        $classFromVendor: 'CompanyName\Utils\ClassFromVendor'
    public: true
```

But this throw error:

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to
>   AppBundle\Service\DecorateArticle::__construct() must be an instance
>   of CompanyName\Utils\ClassFromVendor or null, string given

How to inject vendor class to Service?

Maybe there is a better way to do what I do?
I'm not sure if I can use injections in services.yml and setters (setNews) in one class.

Comment: It's less that you have injection issues and more that you're passing a string instead of an object. Check your arguments

Comment: Yes you can use both constructor and setter injection in the same service definition.  However, look closely at your arguments in the service definition.  Notice anything missing from the classFromVendor?  Probably worth while to review the docs on creating services so you understand why the difference is important.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
AppBundle\Service\DecorateArticle:
        arguments:
            decorateArticle: '@AppBundle\Service\DecorateArticle'
            classFromVendor: companyName.utils.ClassFromVendor
        public: true


companyName.utils.ClassFromVendor:
    class: CompanyName\Utils\ClassFromVendor
    public: false
```

I don`t know if the decorateArticle works, because you use as a parameter the same service..
I think this is de correct way to pass a class as a parameter to the service.

Comment: Well no.  Might try again.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 4 I needed to inject vendor class into one of my services:

```
 jiraRestApi.ClassFromVendor:
    class: JiraRestApi\Issue\IssueService
    public: false

CM\Infrastructure\IssueJira\IssueJiraDbRepository:
    arguments: ['@jiraRestApi.ClassFromVendor', '@parameter_bag']
    public: false
```

Where jiraRestApi.ClassFromVendor as you might think is a vendor class.

My IssueJiraDbRepository.php has a constructor:

```
public function __construct(JiraRestApi Issue, ParameterBagInterface $params){ ...
```

So in your case, I assume you have to make service.yaml:

```
CompanyName.ClassFromVendor:
    class: CompanyName\Utils\ClassFromVendor
    public: false

AppBundle\Service\DecorateArticle:
    arguments:['@CompanyName.ClassFromVendor']
    public: true
```

Remember about '@' in the argument. Constructor in controller should stay the same:

```
public function __construct(CustomDecorator $customDecorator)
{
    $this->customDecorator = $customDecorator;
}
```

Treat services.yaml as a constructor for your controllers. Arguments placed there will be used to create instances of a controller. Error you have is saying that you passed string instead of object. If you have problems you can always use autowire, in most cases it's enough. Remember that new entries in service.yaml will replace previous ones.